# Angular _this.exams.slice is not a function - Angular error on initialization

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm encountering an error on Angular I don't know how to solve.

```
ERROR TypeError: _this.exams.slice is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next (exam.service.ts:17)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:195)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:133)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:38)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:79)
```

I'm trying to fetch the following

Exam.service

```
import { Exam } from '../models/exam.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ExamService {
  private exams: Exam[] = [];
  private examsUpdated = new Subject<Exam[]>();

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getExams() {
    this.httpClient.get<Exam[]>('http://localhost:3000/api/exam')
    .subscribe((examData) => {
      this.exams = examData;
      this.examsUpdated.next([...this.exams]);
    });
  }

  getExamsUpdateListener() {
    return this.examsUpdated.asObservable();
  }

  addExam(
    question: string,
    answer1: string,
    answer2: string,
    answer3: string,
    answer4: string,
    difficulty: string,
    year: string,
    subject: string) {
    const exam: Exam = {
      id: null,
      question: question,
      answer1: answer1,
      answer2: answer2,
      answer3: answer3,
      answer4: answer4,
      difficulty: difficulty,
      year: year,
      subject: subject,
    };
    this.httpClient.post<{message: string}>('http://localhost:3000/api/exam', exam)
      .subscribe((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData.message);
        this.exams.push(exam);
        this.examsUpdated.next([...this.exams]);
      });
  }
}
```

Express middleware

```
app.get("/api/exam", (req, res, next) =>{
  Exam.find().then(documents => {
    res.status(200).json({
      exams: documents
    })
  })
});
```

Angular component

```
  exams: Exam[] = [];
  private examSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public examService: ExamService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.examService.getExams();
    this.examSubscription = this.examService.getExamsUpdateListener().subscribe((exams: Exam[]) => {
      this.exams = exams;
    });
  }
```

Exam Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const examSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  question: {type: String, required: true},
  answer1: String,
  answer2: String,
  answer3: String,
  answer4: String,
  difficulty: String,
  year: String,
  subject: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Exam', examSchema);
```

It happens when I try to pull the data on initialization of the component.
Changing the Express middleware to the following collects the MongoDB in the console, so it seems so be related to the middleware.

```
app.get("/api/exam", (req, res, next) =>{
  Exam.find().then(documents => {
    console.log(documents)
    })
  })
```

Hope you can see what is wrong, otherwise I can provide more info! Thanks

Comment: What you posted doesn't correspond to the error message. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Alright I'm sorry. I tried to provide enough information since a lot of components are working together. Did my edit help at all?

Comment: Provide the complete code for `exam.service.ts`

Comment: You still don't seem to actually be slicing anywhere. Please read the article and cut the code down to the least that recreates the problem.

Comment: @SunilSingh note **not** the complete code, the OP should be more concise when asking.

Comment: I am not slicing anywhere, which is why the error message is so wierd to me. I provided the complete code for exam.service (but apparently I'm not allowed to, so I don't know).

Comment: If you `console.log(JSON.stringify(examData))` in the first line of that `subscribe`, what is logged?

Comment: That returns the complete database, which is just one item atm, so: {"exams":[{"_id":"5bcb811757a7250b64edb991","question":"Første spørgsmål","answer1":"Correct answer","answer2":"Wrong answer 1","answer3":"Wrong answer 2","answer4":"Wrong answer 3","difficulty":"Let","year":"2015","subject":"Hjerte","__v":0}]}

Comment: Maybe you want `[...this.exams.exams]` instead then, as `this.exams` is an object (which also has an `exams` property), not an array

Comment: What you just wrote there works! However I'm not sure how, but I'll take a look. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the following snippets

```
this.examsUpdated.next([...this.exams]);
```

by

```
this.examsUpdated.next(this.exams);
```